# Deleting an entire linked list in C, gone wrong

Tags: c, linked-list, free

So I'm trying to use this function to delete entire singly-linked lists in C.

```
    void zeroList( struct node *head)
    {
        struct node* tempDelete;
        struct node* current = head;

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            tempDelete = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tempDelete);

        }   
    }
```

I am having a problem though, because when I attempt to verify that the list itself has been deleted(by printing it). I'm left with something that looks like this:

```
{ 0->146513968->146513952->146513936-> NULL }
{ 146513920->146514048->146514032->146514016->146514000-> NULL }
{146513984->146514064->146514080->146514096->146514112->146514128->146514144->146514160->146514176-> NULL }
```

I was under the impression that the nodes wouldn't still be there, or at the very least that they'd contain NULL values. Can anyone explain why I'm getting these strange garbage numbers?

Comment: What do you printing exactly?

Comment: The values that I'm printing are ints inside of the struct nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you free memory, it's contents are undefined, and you should not touch them. This is the same reason why you shouldn't set a pointer to a random value you chose(the OS needs to give you access to it.)

The values you're seeing is garbage, and expected, as the OS does not zero memory. If you want to make sure to not have anything on memory, you need to clear the pointers yourself:

```
current = current->next;
tempDelete->next = NULL;
```

PS.: This however, doesn't guarantee the head will be NULL by the end of the function.

Comment: The OS does not *typically* zero memory.  It could if it felt like doing so, though.  You really can't trust anything about a particular location once you no longer own it -- even that it's garbage, or even that its value won't look just like the legit value you stored there before releasing the memory.

Comment: @Charles, thanks for the info. This seems to do the job, however I still get a single artifact at the beginning of each list. Is this because the head can't be guaranteed to be NULL? I'm not sure how I'd go about explicitly setting the head to NULL at the end of the function. I've tried assignment, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: As mentioned, you should not trust the memory after freed: you're *not* supposed to touch head or the list elements after calling your function. Anything you do with the free'd memory is undefined behavior.